# ComboBox conditional item color

Tags: wpf, conditional-statements, styling

I have a simple setup with a ComboBox. I set it's `ItemsSource` to instance of `IReadOnlyList<IDeviceInOut>`. Everything is default and I'm happy with that expect I want to add colouring of text, based on some conditions. All I've found is [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890159/conditionally-changing-the-foreground-of-a-wpf-combobox-item-depending-upon-a-va):

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

The problem is that my condition is not only based on item's property but also on an extension method (`public static string getCustomName(this IDeviceInOut io) {...}`).
So I would need an equivalent of something like this:

```
private void styleItem(TextBlock tb, IDeviceInOut item) {
    if (item.getCustomName() == item.originalName)
        tb.Foreground = defaultNameColor;
    else tb.Foreground = customtNameColor; 
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add an appropriate boolean property to the classes that implement IDeviceInOut, probably in some common abstract base class. Let that property return the result of `this.getCustomName() == originalName`. Then use the property in a DataTrigger Binding.

Answer (score 1):

Create simple Setter in the Style (no triggers etc.), e.g.:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={local:DeviceInOutToColorConverter ActiveBrush=Navy, CustomBrush=Pink, DefaultBrush=AliceBlue}}}" />
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Then create custom converter class that computes proper color for given entity, e.g:

```
public class DeviceInOutToColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public Brush ActiveBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush DefaultBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush CustomBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IDeviceInOut item)
        {
            if (item.IsActive)
            {
                return ActiveBrush;
            }

            if (item.getCustomName() != item.originalName)
            {
                return CustomBrush;
            }

            return DefaultBrush;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you wish to have UI that reflects changes e.g. in the IsActive property, try MultiBinding that contains inner Binding objects pointing to properties that shall trigger UI refresh.

Comment: I don't think updating is an issue, I'm already updating the names correctly when they change. However I'm not sure how to write this converter. I've seen some examples but I don't understand the whole concept. Can you show me how to configure it so I end up with more-less similar method to the one in original question?

Comment: Ok, it's working partially... Do you know how to set the style so that the "front"/selected item is affected as well? I've set this to `<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>` and only items on the list are changed, and not the item that is visible when the list is collapsed. I've spend half a day on this already and it's only half working... :/

Comment: I think the answer will depend on your style implementation, e.g. have a look:
https://github.com/qube7/qcomposite/blob/master/Qube7.Composite.Vsix/ProjectTemplates/Application/Styles/Controls.ComboBox.xaml
The template for ComboBox may use ContentPresenter with ContentTemplate set to ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate. You could possibly use it (e.g. try to specify SelectionBoxItemTemplate). Still, ComboBox may dispaly in various modes (editable/ non-editable) so depending on your cases you may need to play with ComboBox.Foreground as well.

Comment: Yea, I've realized I can set Foreground directly on the combo and don't need to mess with this XAML BS, just as I starter to write my own combo box...